# Flash Actionscript 3 "Limit turns"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am building a random spelling quiz and it works fine. To make it better I would like to add a lot of words but if I do this ten I only want a user to spell 10 of these words correctly. My question is where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your words in a list:

```
var words:Array = ['chicken', 'pig', 'cow', 'sheep'];
```

---

### Shuffle the list of words

[Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) implementation taken from http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}

var shuffledWords:Array = shuffle(words);
trace(shuffledWords); // Prints ['sheep', 'chicken', 'cow', 'pig']
```

### Take a slice

```
var selectedWords = shuffledWords.slice(0, 2);
trace(selectedWords); // Prints ['sheep', 'chicken']
```

---

In this case the slice contains only two elements, but you can change it to 10 or whatever number you want.

Now you can use the words in `selectedWords` to play the spelling quiz.

Comment: BopperH Thank you very much for your answer this is what I had in my head. Thanks